# Add interactive checkbox to PDF using itext 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm trying to add an AcroField checkbox to a PDF that's being generated  by iText7 pdfHTML. This is not working by default, I saw someone suggest using a custom tag worker but as much as I tried I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone have any idea how to implement this? Or an  example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a very simple example to show you how one can create a custom tag worker and add an acrofield to a document while html to pdf processing.

Look at the next snippet:

```
class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
@Override
public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
    if (tag.name().equals("input")) {
        if (AttributeConstants.CHECKBOX.equals(tag.getAttribute(AttributeConstants.TYPE))) {
            return new AcroInputTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I've introduced a custom tag worker factory which will create default tagworkers for all tags except for the one I've specified (`<input type="checkbox">`).

Now let's add an acrofield to the document on `<input type="checkbox">` processing:

```
class AcroInputTagWorker extends InputTagWorker {

public AcroInputTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
    super(element, context);
    PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(context.getPdfDocument(), true)
            .addField(PdfFormField.createCheckBox(context.getPdfDocument(), new Rectangle(100, 700, 30, 30), "checkbox", "Off"));
}
```

That's basically it. The resultant pdf for a very simple html file (basically, just one line: `<input type="checkbox">`) looks as this:

[image]

Now let's briefly discuss what can be improved:

1) you may want to check whether CHECKED attribute is set and consider it while setting the acrofield's value (in the example above I've just set it as "Off")

2) you need to create different acrofield's name values (I've just used "checkbox")

3) you may want to render the acrofield not at a certain position, predefined before html to pdf processing. You may want to let iText define its position dynamically depending on where the `input` tag is placed.

In that case the solution would be more difficult. You will need to create your own CheckBox element (probably extended from a`Paragraph`) and a renderer for it (probably extended from a `ParagraphRender`). Then you will need to override its `layout` method (perhaps just call `super.layout()` to get the coordinates of the paragraph and only then add the acrofield to the document). That's not easy, but it's certainly worth a try! And if you're not successful, you can always ask another SO question :)

Comment: I ended up extending InputFieldRenderer  and overriding the draw method. This gave me access to the current area.